The function $f(x)=|x^3+x^2+3x+\sin x|(2+\sin(1/x))$ if $x≠0$, $0$ if $x=0$, has absolute minimum in its domain. State true or false.
The function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}|x^3+x^2+3x+\sin x|(2+\sin(1/x)), &  x\ne 0\\ 0, &  x=0\end{cases}$$ has absolute minimum in its domain. State true or false.
In this question, differentiation would be quite lengthy to do. What alternative can I use for this?

Prove the function is positive except at $0$.

What u tried include in a question

An absolute value is always positive or 0. Sin has a range from -1 to 1. Regardless of its value, the term in parantheses is always 1 or greater. $f(x\to 0)\to 0$ by inspection. Otherwise, this is the product of two positive numbers which must itself be positive. It follows that the minimum of the function is 0.

For the next time, show us your efforts to solve the exercise and explain us your doubts instead of putting the exercise text and asking us to solve it for you!

Note that $1 \leq 2 + {\rm sin}(1/x)) \leq 3$, and that $| x^3 + x^2 + 3x + {\rm sin}(x) |> 0$ (for $x \neq 0$).
So it is easy to see that the absolute minimum (equal to $0$) occurs at $x=0$, which is in its domain.

Don't answer these kind of questions. Read community guidelines of MSE
